# Автоматическая подгонка элементов на форме

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

На форме два `picturebox`. Когда мы меняем размер формы, то они "уплывают". В html  например есть технология резиновых макетов. Как сделать чтобы `picturebox-ы` автоматом изменялись? Ставлю `Dock` - исчезает `Anchor`.

Answer (score 2):

Если `2 PicturesBox`, то можно кинуть на форму `SplitContainer`. У него задаешь `Anchor = Top, Bottom, Left, Right`. В каждую панель помещаешь PicturesBox. У каждого задаешь `Dock = Fill`.

Растягиваешь форму, пропорционально растягиваются картинки.

Comment: Можно еще выставить у SplitConteiner свойство Orientation. В зависимости от того что тебе нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно также использовать TableLayout - создать два столбца и одну строку, у них установить пропорциональный размер в 50%. Поместить в каждую ячейку PictureBox. У каждого PictureBox установить Dock в Fill